# Is it allowed to use over() in the having clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to use  `over(partition by ...)` in the `having` clause.

This is my code which gives the error:

> group function is nested too deeply

```
select resort, discipline, gender, count(1)
from races
group by resort, discipline, gender
having sum(count(1)) over (partition by resort, discipline) > 10;
```

Is there a way to use `over()` in the `having` clause or is there an alternative?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always nest it:

```
WITH cte AS (
  select resort, discipline, gender, count(1) AS cnt
  from races
  group by resort, discipline, gender
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, sum(cnt) over (partition by resort, discipline) AS s
  FROM cte
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE s > 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to select as subset.

```
select resort, discipline, gender from 
(select resort, discipline, gender, sum(count(1)) over (partition by resort, discipline) groupcount
from races
group by resort, discipline, gender) Records
where groupcount > 10
```